# Can I remove the nasty rubber smell from new equipment?

Tags: exercise-equipment, maintenance

I just bought a [Burn Machine](http://theburnmachine.com/) device which has two rotating handles within a frame. It is weighted and functions similar to using a speedbag (see picture below). I've been using it a lot ever since I received it, but the smell of the rubber handles is so overpowering makes my use of the device very limited during sessions.

I've tried letting it sit out in the open air to try and let the smell dissipate (I keep it in my cubicle in a very large office area, not really a lot of circulation but not terrible), and I've also tried cleaning it with some mild soap and water which didn't help much either.

What can I do to remove the smell of the rubber and make it more bearable?

[image: The Burn Machine]

Comment: The only other method I heard of except letting it sit in open air for a few days is heating it for a few hours (around 70deg Celsius in an oven) but I never tried it so can't say if it works and if the rubber is ok afterwards. A strong rubber smell usually indicates cheap plasticizers...

Comment: Baking it in an oven sounds like it could be dangerous. It already smells bad enough (like rubber tires). I wonder if that would really help.

Comment: Like I said never tried it just heard it. I would only try when desperate ^^. Here is something I found after a quick google doesn't say if they tried the oven and if it worked. But (low) heat seams to be key in loosing the plasticizers. http://bbs.homeshopmachinist.net/threads/42335-How-do-I-get-that-dam-plasticizer-smell-out

Comment: When I first got my bumpers, that rubber smell was very overpowering.  They live in my garage, and it took a couple weeks for the smell to calm down a bit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a smell, not using the equipment in a program.

Answer (score 2):

See the related question, comments, and answer about residue from rubber-capped weights at [Rubber residue on weights stains clothing, carpets, hands](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22316/rubber-residue-on-weights-stains-clothing-carpets-hands/22411#22411)

Hope it will be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I read that a combo of vinegar and water (1/5 vinegar) would remove the smell or Murphy's Oil soap.  Worse case I would use Sports Tape to wrap over the handles.

[image: sports tape]